# How to execute ‘base64 --decode’ on selected text in Vim?

Tags: vim, base64

I’m trying to execute `base64 --decode` on a piece of text selected in Visual mode, but it is the entire line that seems to be passed to the `base64` command, not just the current selection.

I’m selecting the text in Visual mode, then entering Normal mode, so that my command line looks like this:

```
:'<,'>!base64 --decode
```

How can I pass only the selected piece of the line to a shell-command invocation in Vim?

Comment: Do you want to replace the selected text?

Comment: Replacing would be OK, plain output to the console would be OK as well.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If the text to be passed to the shell command is first yanked to
a register, say, the unnamed one, one can use the following command:

```
:echo system('base64 --decode', @")
```

It is possible to combine copying the selected text and running the
command into a single Visual-mode key mapping:

```
:vnoremap <leader>64 y:echo system('base64 --decode', @")<cr>
```

The mapping can further be modified to replace the selected text with
the output of the shell command via the expression register:

```
:vnoremap <leader>64 c<c-r>=system('base64 --decode', @")<cr><esc>
```

Comment: It is possible to echo the first example into a new vim tab?

Comment: Or how would I make a macro out if it?

Comment: @shredding:  Just add a command opening an empty buffer in a new tab page between copying and calling `base64`: `:vnoremap <leader>64 y:tabe\|pu!=system('base64 -d', @@)<cr>`.

Comment: Bonus points for a function that toggles between base64 and plaintext via the same keybind?

Comment: If it was possible to toggle base64, there would be no need for base64 -d option. Example: Any 4 letter word can be base64 decoded or encoded.

Answer (score 14):

You can use Python instead, which should work.

Select lines that you want to decode in Visual mode (via <kbd>V</kbd>), then execute the following command:

```
:'<,'>!python -m base64 -d
```

Comment: This suffers the same problem as the original command in the question. Namely, the Python process in this case is fed the whole lines that the current selection spans, rather than the exact character range selected.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to replace the text with the output of [`base64`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/base64.1.html), use something like

```
:vnoremap <leader>64 y:let @"=system('base64 --decode', @")<cr>gvP
```

Explanation:

- `y` → Yank the currently selected text to register `"`. This deselects the text.
- `:let @"=system('base64 --decode', @")` → Pass the contents of the `"` register to `base64` and write the results into the same register `"`.
- `gv` → Select the previously selected text again.
- `P` → Paste the text from register `"` which replaces the currently selected text.

Comment: I added these two lines to my .vimrc for encoding and decoding:
`vnoremap <leader>b y:let @"=system('base64 -w 0', @")<cr>gvP` and `vnoremap <leader>B y:let @"=system('base64 --decode', @")<cr>gvP`

Answer (score 0):

Base64 encode/decode visual-selected region in buffer and clipboard,
put this in ~/.vimrc, and use F2 to encode selection, and F3 to decode selection

```
" 1. base64-encode(visual-selection) -> F2 -> encoded base64-string
:vnoremap <F2> c<c-r>=system("base64 -w 0", @")<cr><esc>

" 2. base64-decode(visual-selection) -> F3 -> decoded string
:vnoremap <F3> c<c-r>=system("base64 -d", @")<cr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a script that uses Python and the `base64` module to provide base64 decode and encode commands. It’d be pretty simple to support any other base64 program as well, as long as it reads from stdin — just replace `python -m base64 -e` with the encoding command and `python -m base64 -d` with the decoding command.

```
function! Base64Encode() range
    " go to first line, last line, delete into @b, insert text
    " note the substitute() call to join the b64 into one line
    " this lets `:Base64Encode | Base64Decode` work without modifying the text
    " at all, regardless of line length -- although that particular command is
    " useless, lossless editing is a plus
    exe "normal! " . a:firstline . "GV" . a:lastline . "G"
    \ . "\"bdO0\<C-d>\<C-r>\<C-o>"
    \ . "=substitute(system('python -m base64 -e', @b), "
    \ . "'\\n', '', 'g')\<CR>\<ESC>"
endfunction

function! Base64Decode() range
    let l:join = "\"bc"
    if a:firstline != a:lastline
        " gJ exits vis mode so we need a cc to change two lines
        let l:join = "gJ" . l:join . "c"
    endif
    exe "normal! " . a:firstline . "GV" . a:lastline . "G" . l:join
    \ . "0\<C-d>\<C-r>\<C-o>"
    \ . "=system('python -m base64 -d', @b)\<CR>\<BS>\<ESC>"
endfunction

command! -nargs=0 -range -bar Base64Encode <line1>,<line2>call Base64Encode()
command! -nargs=0 -range -bar Base64Decode <line1>,<line2>call Base64Decode()
```

Some features this provides:

- Supports ranges, converts only the current line by default (use `:%Base64Encode` to encode the whole file, for example, and it’ll work as expected from within visual mode, although it only converts whole lines)
- Doesn’t leave output indented — all indents (tabs/spaces) is encoded into base64, and then preserved when decoding.
- Supports being combined with other commands with `|`

Relevant `:help` tags: `user-functions`, `func-range`, `i_0_CTRL-D`, `i_CTRL-R_CTRL-O`, `expr-register`, `system()`, `user-commands`, `command-nargs`, `command-range`, `:normal`