# How to filter the contents of a Visual selection that does not span an entire line through an external command in Vim?

Tags: vim

I would like to filter a visual selection in Vim through a command. The way I know filters always the complete lines over which the visual selection extends:

Selecting `a test` in the line

```
this is a test
```

and typing

```
:'<,'>!echo "the result"
```

will result in

```
the result
```

But I want:

```
this is the result
```

Comment: See also “[How to execute ‘base64 --decode’ on selected text in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845671/how-to-execute-base64-decode-on-selected-text-in-vim)”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following mappings that adhere the behavior of the `!` linewise
filtering commands (see `:helpg \*!\*` and `:help v_!`).

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>! :set opfunc=ProgramFilter<cr>g@
vnoremap <silent> <leader>! :<c-u>call ProgramFilter(visualmode(), 1)<cr>
function! ProgramFilter(vt, ...)
    let [qr, qt] = [getreg('"'), getregtype('"')]
    let [oai, ocin, osi, oinde] = [&ai, &cin, &si, &inde]
    setl noai nocin nosi inde=

    let [sm, em] = ['[<'[a:0], ']>'[a:0]]
    exe 'norm!`' . sm . a:vt . '`' . em . 'x'

    call inputsave()
    let cmd = input('!')
    call inputrestore()

    let out = system(cmd, @")
    let out = substitute(out, '\n$', '', '')
    exe "norm!i\<c-r>=out\r"

    let [&ai, &cin, &si, &inde] = [oai, ocin, osi, oinde]
    call setreg('"', qr, qt)
endfunction
```

Comment: Very good! Sorry that my question was not too precise (ditto kev). It was actually targeting the most general case in which I want to do both: 1) pass the visual selection to a command 2) specify this command in vim using short commands; i.e. the vim command should take the 'base64 --decode' in your example as an argument.

Comment: In other words it should effectively do the same as the filter command !, just for the visual selection only, not complete lines.

Comment: @user429540:  Now I see.  Take a look at the updated answer listing the mappings written in attempt to implement that filtering commands.

Comment: How do I call it? :'<,'>,! echo (where , is my leader)? For me it still does the same thing like :'<,'>! echo (without the leader).

Comment: @user429540:  Leader is a configurable key which is convenient for creating mappings (see `:help mapleader`); by default, it is the backslash character.  The mappings above are supposed to be used the same way as default `!` filtering: Select a piece of text in Visual mode, then press your leader key (again, backslash by default) followed by `!`; or do not select anything, press this key combination, then use a motion command (e.g. `w`, `W`, `)`, etc.).

Comment: I get it. I was typing too slowly. the ! command should follow the leader key immediately. The only odd behaviour I still see is that a whitespace preceeding the visual mode selection is replaced by the commands output.

Comment: @user429540:  That is a bug: auto-indenting rules interfere when output of a command contains newline characters.  Please, try the updated code.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\%V` to match inside the Visual area:

```
:'<,'>s/\%V.*\%V/\=system('echo -n "the result"')
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, is a little long however. What would a vmap lookk like which takes the shell command as parameter?

Comment: .. and of course in my example the command does not depend on the visual selection which can in general be the case. So how can I pass the visual selection as argument to the command?